How to delete a row from a datagridview and database using a data access layer
I am working on building a Windows Form with a DataGridView that displays the information in a SQL server. The Windows Form looks like this:

When the Delete button is pressed, I have a function that takes the row's EmpId and deletes that row from the interface and the SQL server through a Data Access Layer.
        public static void DeleteById(int EmpId)
        {
            Organization.EmployeesDataTable dtEmpTable = new Organization.EmployeesDataTable();
            OrganizationTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter empAdapter = new OrganizationTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
            empAdapter.Fill(dtEmpTable);

            foreach(Organization.EmployeesRow ur in dtEmpTable)
            {
                if(ur.EmpID == EmpId)
                {
                    ur.Delete();
                }
            }
            empAdapter.Update(dtEmpTable);

        }

however when I run the code it gets caught up at empAdapter.Update(dtEmpTable);. Here's the error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@IsNull_".'
What is wrong with my logic? My assumption is that the .Update function is confused because the row has been deleted so there's nothing to 'update'. If that's the case, what should I do to delete the row?
I am expecting the row to disappear on the Windows Form and for the row to be gone in the SQL server as well.


First look at your update command and make sure it is correct.
If you are going to use the datatable after deleting the row, you will get an error. Use: dtEmpTable.Rows.Remove(ur); instead of ur.Delete();
See: Deleting specific rows from DataTable.
After you remove the row from dtEmpTable, accept changes: dtEmpTable.AcceptChanges();

This is official recommendation from Microsoft :
To delete records directly from a database
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/directly-access-the-database-with-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/save-data-with-the-tableadapter-dbdirect-methods?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp
I hope it helps !
